# Varnish returning wrong backend

Tags: varnish

Having an issue with Varnish returning the wrong backend.  I have several backends listening on ports 8080 through 8095 on vhosts in Apache.  I configured my Varnish backends like so:

```
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.0.1";
}

backend default {
    .host = "192.168.0.1";
    .port = "8094";
    .connect_timeout =  20s; #600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 20s; #600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 20s; #600s;
}

backend default_mobile {
    .host = "192.168.0.1";
    .port = "8093";
    .connect_timeout =  20s; #600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 20s; #600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 20s; #600s;
}

backend secondary {
    .host = "192.168.0.1";
    .port = "8082";
    .connect_timeout =  20s; #600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 20s; #600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 20s; #600s;
}

backend secondary_mobile {
    .host = "192.168.0.1";
    .port = "8083";
    .connect_timeout =  20s; #600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 20s; #600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 20s; #600s;
}
```

This works well most of the time but after some time (several hours) we'll get reports of users seeing the wrong site under the wrong URL.  For instance they'll go to www.example.com and get a page from the secondary_mobile backend.  It's always the same backend that is returned incorrectly and the URL in the browser will show the intended site (www.example.com).  We don't have any sort of redirects in Apache so I'm unsure how it's getting confused.  Here's an example of how I set the backends:

```
....
if ( req.http.host ~ "example.com$" ) { 
    set req.backend = default;
    set req.http.host = "www.example.com";
} else if ( req.http.host ~ "^(www.)?example2.com$" ) { 
    set req.backend = secondary;
    set req.http.host = "www.example2.com";
} else if ( req.http.host ~ "^(m.)?example2.com$" ) { 
    set req.backend = secondary_mobile;
    set req.http.host = "m.example2.com";
....
```

I thought manually specifying the host was enough but apparently not.  The Varnish docs don't have a lot on the subject either.

Comment: Do you have the logs of one of the requests that went wrong? You can also add some log statements to help identify in the logs what's going on .

Comment: I don't have them anymore but I did notice the requests that didn't serve properly hadn't specified a set backend in the varnishlog output.  I think that just meant they were served from cache though.

Comment: Actually I cannot see a big problem in the given example configuration. Regarding redirects, keep in mind that you do not need mod_rewrite for that. A common request to the folder "/xyz" will be redirected to "/xyz/" . Additionally I miss something to handle IP based requests (e.g. http://1.2.3.4/xyz ) or even complete different host names (e.g. http://crazybot/xyz ). Without anymore details it's hard to investigate. We are using some comparable set-ups but don't have this problem (it hasn't been reported yet).

Comment: Well, running `varnishlog -i Backend_health` does return the default backend which is what I want but the response is definitely from another backend.  It's also having timeout issues.  Which I thought I had handled with a grace setting of 7 minutes.  Back to the drawing board is seems.

Comment: Please check if the data from the wrong back-end isn't staled or expired data. Usually you can check the Age header for this. I assume that everything is working fine but you are getting this data in case your back-end doesn't respond fast enough.

Comment: @ThomasHibbard Did you sort this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @jakenoble Not yet.  We've decided to rebuild our environment from the ground up.  If I find a solution then I'll let you know.